# How to set identity token and access token timeout in run time using Identity Server 4.0

Tags: identityserver4, identity

I am using Identity Server 4 with my ASP.NET Core. It is working fine. I tried to set the Access Token lifetime based on the roles in run time but it always take database configure value, it's not overwriting the run time value

[image]

[image]

I tried to set in both places Login and GetProfileDataAsync but its not working as expected.

Is there any reason for this behavior?